# Is it possible to evaluate an expression in launchd's ProgramArguments array?

Tags: macos, plist, osx-elcapitan, launchd, launchctl

I have a `~/Library/LaunchAgents/setenv.JAVA_HOME.plist` file which contains a `/bin/launchctl` call as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>setenv.JAVA_HOME</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/launchctl</string>
        <string>setenv</string>
        <string>JAVA_HOME</string>
        <string>$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8)</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ServiceIPC</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Problem is, the `$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8)` expression is not evaluated and instead the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is assigned the literal value `$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8)`.

Question is: is it possible to compose my plist file so that the expression is evaluated and not treated as a literal value? And, if so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've discovered, `<string>` entries are passed as string literals, but `$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8)` is a bash shell expression. According to [the launchd.plist documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html), `ProgramArguments` only takes an array of strings, so there does not appear to be any way of marking an argument as an expression.

However, I think the simple solution is to run `/bin/bash` with the `-c` argument, followed by the command line you want to execute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>test.so</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/bash</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>/bin/launchctl setenv JAVA_HOME $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8)</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ServiceIPC</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a million!